# Loading data with multiple delimiter (only in some cases) in a particular data file using apache-pig

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig

```
150060275,NON-CRIMINAL,LOST PROPERTY,Monday,01/19/2015,14:00,MISSION,NONE,18TH ST / VALENCIA ST,-122.42158168137,37.7617007179518,"(37.7617007179518, -122.42158168137)",15006027571000
150098210,ROBBERY,"ROBBERY, BODILY FORCE",Sunday,02/01/2015,15:45,TENDERLOIN,NONE,300 Block of LEAVENWORTH ST,-122.414406029855,37.7841907151119,"(37.7841907151119, -122.414406029855)",15009821003074
```

In the second row the third field has a ',' in between which shouldn't be taken as a delimiter.How do i solve this?

if i use STRPLIT(), then it works for the 2nd row, but generates wrong result for the 1st row.

Answer (score 0):

Load it into a single field, replace the comma and space with | and then use strsplit on each line.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,', ','|');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE STRSPLIT(B.$0,',',13);-- Assuming there are 13 fields.
```

Alternatively, you can use [CSVExcelStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html) and [PiggyBank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank).